# connecting to a mysql container: what's the equivalent of localhost inside a docker compose project?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have this `docker-compose.yml` file, which has one service (`log_app`) trying to write to a mysql database (`mydb`).

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  mydb:
    container_name: mysql_data
    restart: always
    image: mysql:8.0.22
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PW}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ib
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PW}
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
  tws:
    build: .
    container_name: ib_logger_app
    volumes:
      - ./ib/IBController.ini:/root/IBController/IBController.ini
      - ./ib/jts.ini:/root/Jts/jts.ini
    environment:
      TRADING_MODE: ${TWS_TRADING_MODE}
      TWSUSERID: ${TWS_USER_ID}
      TWSPASSWORD: ${TWS_PASSWORD}
      FIXUSERID:
      FIXPASSWORD:
      XVFB_ARGS: -ac -screen 0 1024x768x16 +extension RANDR
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5901:5900
    depends_on:
      - mydb
  log_app:
    build: log_app/ib_client
    environment:
      - IB_GATEWAY_URLNAME=tws
      - IB_GATEWAY_URLPORT=4004
      - MKT_DATA_TYPE=4
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - tws
      - mydb
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

When I run this on a bare metal server, everything works fine, but in that situation, I connect to `localhost` on port `3306`. This doesn't seem to work here, though. I get

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (99)
```

I've been reading that 3306 is still the right port, but `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are wrong now. Neither works for me.

I've also seen some answers on this site that recommend changing `localhost` to `host.docker.internal`, but that gives me this:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host.docker.internal' (111)
```

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the overall network environment and the host names available to call other containers.  `localhost` in Docker is usually "this container".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host name will be the container name as defined in your docker-compose file.

In your example, you should use `mydb:3306` instead of `localhost:3306`

**EDIT**:

one way to ensure that is to `exec` into the container that you want to connect from and run:

```
telnet mydb 3306
```

and see if it works (but t might require additional installation of `telnet`).